# How to choose a selector based on the index position of an array using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have div's set up that represent the days of a pay-period and an array that holds the employee times each day- What Im trying to do is .text the input time in the correct div for that day.  The 'wt' below is the wArray.length.  What am I missing? I have also tried using jquerys :nth child selector and had no luck there either.

```
$('.daysContain:eq(wt)').text('Time In: ' + timeIn);
```

Comment: I achieved the correct results by using:  $('.daysContain').find('div').eq(wt).text('Time In: ' + timeIn);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like below,

```
$('.daysContain:eq('+ wt +')').text('Time In: ' + timeIn);
```

or you can use [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) function like below,

```
$('.daysContain').eq(wt).text('Time In: ' + timeIn);
```

Comment: In this instance better use method .eq() instead selector :eq.

Comment: both of these wrote the correct the text but all the div's inside the class vanished

Comment: @mcG73 Well that is because of `.text('Time In: ' + timeIn);`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Im trying to get the timepicker input val to display in the correct div- the .daysContain parents 10 day divs and each day div parents 3 divs- Maybe I should use a class for each of the days within the .daysContain class

Comment: @mcG73 May be you want to try `.append` / `.prepend` based on where you want `Time In ...` text.